# Selectize.js border missing in an inline form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, selectize.js

The border left of the year is sometimes missing in medium to large devices. This only occurs when the selectize form is inline. And I'm using bootstrap columns to stack them horizontally. Please see the image below:

[image: Selectize]

Please see fiddle below for live demo. And make sure to make up some space for the rendering for it to be shown as inline. Also if you try to zoom in and out it randomly appears.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crtdhbss/)

What I already did:
I already tried adding `padding`,`margin`, re-positioning using `left`, `right`.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, but in my case I had a label to the left of the selector and was using a flex-box based layout. The left border would appear and disappear when varying the viewport width. Could not isolate it.  Worked around it by adding fixed width to the preceding label.

Comment: Same problem here - it comes and goes probably as you suggest. Your fix is the answer to the problem.

Comment: Looks like it happens when the Bootsrap computed column width is non-integer, eg 149.5px. So some rounding error in Selectize? I'm surprised someone else hasn't seen it. This in Chrome, for me.